# Confidence Interval for h2o Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I noticed that there are a couple functions designed to calculate the confidence interval for models built using `randomForest` packages, such as `rfPredVar` in `RFinfer`. I am wondering if anyone knows any functions like `rfPredVar` that can calculate the confidence interval for RF models built using `h2o` package. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, there is no built-in functionality for generating confidence intervals within H2O.

*As an aside:* It says in the docs that the **RFInfer** package only works for regression trees.  So if you happen to be performing binary classification instead of regression and want CIs for the AUC or cross-validated AUC estimate of model performance, then you can use a package I wrote called [cvAUC](https://github.com/ledell/cvAUC) for your Random Forest predictions or any type of model predictions.

Comment: Hi Erin, thank you so much for answering my question. As I was googling for this question, I saw you answering many similar questions elsewhere and I did looked into your code. Very impressive I have to say. However, my forecast are not binary, so I cannot use your package in my situation.